# Speed query very slow on TimescaleDB

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I created a table with the command:

```
CREATE TABLE public.g_dl (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    id_tram integer,
    site_id character varying(40),
    user_id character varying(40),
    app_code character varying(40),
    time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL
);


SELECT create_hypertable('g_dl','time');
```

Then I insert an amount of about 34 million records.

The query speed is very good, the amount of Ram used by the docker container is about 500MB-1.2GB. But query speed gets a problem after I insert amount of 1.8 million records, the time field is out of order before I had inserted it.

I use DBbeaver and get the message "You might need to increase max_locks_per_transaction". Then I change that value up
increase max_locks_per_transaction = 1000

Query speed is very slow and the amount of ram used by docker is 10GB - 12GB. What I'm doing wrong way. Pls let me know.

Outout when explain:

```
EXPLAIN analyze select * from g_dlquantracts gd  where id_tram = 300
```

Raw JSON explain:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bA5EwcWMUn5oTUirHFD25cSU1cYGwGLo/view?usp=sharing

Formatted execution plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/tM57

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the slow query to the question.

Comment: Gather  (cost=1000.00..793769.40 rows=148 width=718) (actual time=5444.354..5534.070 rows=1660 loops=1) @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: No. Please edit the question, don't write a comment. And we need the *whole* plan.

Comment: File explain https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bA5EwcWMUn5oTUirHFD25cSU1cYGwGLo/view?usp=sharing @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Avoid JSON plans. That plan does not match your query at all, and it does not use Jit.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe JIT default is off in postgresql.conf

Comment: That's my point. Your question writes about `Timing: Generation 138.697 ms, Inlining 165.385 ms, Optimization 5049.030 ms, Emission 2541.678 ms`, which is JIT output. Also, the query in the question has one `WHERE` condition, while the execution plan is for a query with two conditions.